# Force Chrome to Save Password and Autofill

Tags: google-chrome

I have an application I am testing and there is an issue on a tester machine where the autofill of the password messes up my styling.

I have made sure my chrome settings are set up for autofill and saving passwords. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get the chrome browser to ask if I want to remember my password on this one application. My autocomplete is not off on the html side. No clue how I can replicate the issue without having this one page autofill the username and password field. Any ideas?

Comment: I would love to just manually enter them.